# alexa web information services python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, alexa-skills-kit

I want to make a query using Alexa Amazon Web Information Services. I downloaded [AWIS](https://github.com/muhuk/python-awis) and used the code below:

```
import awis
api = awis.AwisApi("ACCESS_ID", "SECRET_ACCESS_KEY")
tree = api.url_info("www.yahoo.com", "Rank", "LinksInCount")
elem = tree.find("//{%s}StatusCode" % api.NS_PREFIXES["alexa"])
assert elem.text == "Success"
```

but I kept on getting the following error:

```
IOError: All 3 requests failed, latest response code is 403][1]
```

What should I do?

Answer (score -1):

i had the same problem, you must have the correct access_id and secret_access_key. but have you checked if your awis service is enabled? have you checked email from aws? is you registration process complete? please first ensure that.

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer.

Comment: yeah dude this is a comment i just had the same problem, these were the things that i did and i found i had problems in my account registration other than that code was perfectly fine. If you've got comment or solution then please do suggest rather than pointing out.

Comment: i've already found my solution, for this problem to work you need to enable the service and have your credit card to have atleast a dollar. There's no solution other than this. code works perfectly fine that's it. other than that i've got no answer.